# How to make the code work on multiple images - HTML&CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, I am working on a website for my friend, and of course, because I can't remember every piece of code on my own sometimes I use www.w3schools.com. I am stuck working on the gallery I want to be able to click on every image and go fullscreen. I used code from: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp)
But I just can't manage this script to work on 2 or more images? It work perfectly fine on first one. Can someone help? I am using the code exactly the same from the link given above :D Thanks!

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Please copy & paste the relevant code here.

Comment: Can you show your attempt...I'm guessing you are not using JavaScript

Comment: Instead of an `id`, use a `class` — in place of `<img id="myImg" ...>` use `<img class="gallery"...>` then, instead of `.getElementById("img01")` use `.getElementsByClassName("gallery")` (or `.querySelectorAll("img.gallery")`) then loop and attach your click-handler to each of the images you found.

Answer (score 1):

found in the code you used :

`var img = document.getElementById('myImg');`
[...]
`img.onclick = function(){`

`getElementById` only finds the **first element with said id**, if you want to set the click event on all images, you need to use a class and loop on it, or to use jquery as it implicitely loops on every element.

Comment: _"getElementById only finds the first element with said id"_ IDs must be unique per page

Comment: in fact they can be multiple and the page will still work, but i am assuming op used duplicate ids and i am only pointing this out :)

Comment: attn: @Markoni — You can put multiples of an `id` on a page, and it may _largely_ work, but there is _no specification_ for what will happen (in fact [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-id-attribute) declares the `id` "must be unique") and all bets are off. `getElementById('someId')` will _usually_ get the first it finds, but it would be perfectly legal for a browser to give you the _last_ one it finds because re-using an id is invalid in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do instead of calling the img id is call a function from the image `onclick` event like this:

```
<img id="myImg1" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Win" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="fx(this)">
```

Edit the script and you can get a function like this for each image to update the modal info:

```
function fx(img){
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = img.src;
captionText.innerHTML = img.alt;
```

}